# How to list offloaded Apps on iPhone / iPad programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, iphone, mobile

Is there any way to find and list all the offloaded apps on the device (iPhone/iPad) in Swift or Objective-C? (I know that I can list all the offloaded apps from the device settings, but needs a solution for my App to show them if there is any possible way to show what has been offloaded from the device. So need a programmatical solution)

Comment: Not possible, same way that you cannot get list of all installed apps.

Comment: Every app in iOS runs inside an individual Sandbox and doesn't have access to the outside system or other applications, only iOS SDK provided APIs. Though, probably I didn't understand your question properly. What do you mean by "offloaded apps"?

Comment: no api, no way, unless apple prepares them.